# Can't update Chrome on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: google-chrome, 17.04

```
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                            
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                           
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB]   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                        
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]                   
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [11.6 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [20.7 kB]    
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [36.5 kB]                        
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B]                                    
Hit:18 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x zesty InRelease                                         
Ign:19 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                       
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease [89.2 kB]                             
Hit:21 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                            
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main i386 Packages [207 kB]             
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Ign:25 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 Packages [210 kB]
Ign:27 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release         
Hit:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release        
Hit:29 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease                    
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.7 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [26.3 kB]  
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [138 kB]
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages   
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe i386 Packages [138 kB]
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [172 kB]
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [228 kB]
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages     
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,840 B]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,140 B]
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                               
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                                                            
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                        
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                          
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                           
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                               
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                               
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                                                            
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                        
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                          
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                           
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                               
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                               
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                                                            
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                        
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                          
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                           
Err:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Ign:32 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                               
Ign:36 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:37 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:39 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:40 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:42 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:44 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 1,531 kB in 13s (112 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (edge/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'edge/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (edge/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
➜  ~ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

➜  ~ sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                            
Ign:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                                                                                                
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                              
Ign:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                                                     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                        
Hit:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                       
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x zesty InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:14 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release                                             
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                   
Hit:16 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                     
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages        
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                    
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu zesty InRelease                     
Hit:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                              
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease                         
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease                        
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease      
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Ign:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all Packages
Err:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:24 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:28 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:29 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:30 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (edge/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'edge/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (edge/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (edge/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (edge/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (edge/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
➜  ~ sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"

➜  ~ sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"

sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"
```

I tried what I saw on internet. I don't want to reinstall. But I can't update it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have error 404 (Not found error) as below. Remove them or comment those ppa or replace them with correct alternative ppa.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Err:31 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                
  404  Not Found
Err:19 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

2) I only use the chrome ppa mentioned below. I am getting regular update for stable releases. I will recommend you to use the same and comment or remove the others.

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main
```

I hope this will fix the problem.

Comment: i also use it in list.d/googlechromlist``` deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
``` in save ```deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: 1) Have you remove the ppa that have 404 error?

Comment: Yes i commented this ```# deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
``` in ```sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list.save``` should i care about ```is configured multiple times``` warnings. now no 404 , for example ```Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease ``` but still chrome is not updated

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the error you will see you have multiple entries for certain repos, e.g. google-chrome. To fix that open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with your default text editor as `root` ( if using gedit, run `sudo -H gedit <file_name>) the comment out those entries with conflict with entries in`/etc/apt/source.list.d/` directory for these repos.

Then there is the

```
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/zesty/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

That would be that it's not available, remove it.

Comment: But my problem is about chrome.

Comment: And who said it wasn't fix those errors and you should be able to update your system...look at your error messages it isn't just chrome alone

Comment: in/etc/apt/source.list.d/` only ``` mongodb-org-``` has 4 entries. other have 2 entrşeslist and list.save. is not that supposed to be?

Comment: make the changes in the `google.list` as stated in your error message

Comment: run `ls /etc/apt/source.list.d/mongodb*` and add to your question not in the comment. The `list.save` are backups just modify the `.list`

Comment: i commented this ```# deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu zesty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
``` in ```sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list.save``` should i care about ```is configured multiple times``` warnings. now no 404 , for example ```Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease ``` but still chrome is not updated

Comment: Yes you should care about that warning also comment out those duplicates